# Extract the desired numbers from the array in the object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have an object with array values , and I want to extract my desired numbers from that with this condition :

First , I should check that if numbers in array are ascending or descending, so if they were one of them, return them , but if they were not check this:

If the numbers in the array are starting from a specific number like **1** or **2** or **1000** and one unit is added each time with a special pattern,like `1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0` or `1000, 10, 1001, 20, 1002, 30,..` the numbers between them (they also should be consecutive) can be extracted, for example: If this was the array

`[1, 300, 400, 2, 500, 650, 3, 800, 1130]`,

the output should be this: `[300, 400, 500, 650, 800, 1130]`,

Or if this was the array:

`[4, 60, 5, 50, 6, 40.3]`,

the output should be this: `[60, 50, 40.3]`

So it doesn't matter how much elements are in between **1** and **2** in **first array** or **4** and **5** in **second array**, but if there were **3** elements between **1** and **2** , Also **3** elements should be between **3** and **4** , and the numbers between them should be **consecutive** , (In **first array** as you can see numbers are ascending and in **second array** numbers are descending. So here we want consecutive numbers between numbers that added 1 unit every time).

And if none of the conditions were met, just return an empty array for every Object.value that doesn't conditions.

More details :

This is my code and I tried to write the code but I don't know how to find numbers and push consecutive number elements between them and push to new array,I can only check ascending or descending numbers in an array.

```
const numbers : {
   number1 : [1, 300,400,2,500,900,3,1000,1100,4,1200,1800], 
   number2 : [0, 1.1, 1, 1.2, 2, 1.3, 3, 1.4],
   number3 : [2, 1000, 3, 980, 4, 700, 5,100, 6, 10],
   number4 : [1000, 1001, 1001.3, 1003, 1014],
   number5 : [34, 76, 0, 50, 0.5, 1010, 0.5],
};

//The output I want : 
// {
//    number1 : [300, 400, 500,900,1000,1100,1200,1800], 
//    number2 : [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4],
//    number3 : [1000, 980, 700, 100, 10],
//    number4 : [1000, 1001, 1001.3, 1003, 1014],
//    number5 : []
// };

const res = {}
for(var i=0, i < Object.values(numbers).length, i++){
  el = Object.values(number)[i];
  if (consecutive(el) == true) {
         res[Object.keys(numbers)[i]] = el;
  }else{
        //check and find numbers that added one unit and extract numbers between them.
  }
}

//This function check if numbers are consecutive or not, for consecutive numbers in array returns the last element and for non-consecutive numbers returns false.
const consecutive = (param) => {
  let res = param.reduce((prev , next) => {
    if(prev < next) {
      if(prev == false) {
        return prev
      }
      return next;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  })
  return (typeof res == 'number') 
}
```

So How can I find the numbers added one unit every time and delete them and push them to new array?

Comment: What constitutes a 'regular pattern'? Do you have a specific set of rules?

Comment: if there were **3** elements between **1** and **2** , Also **3** elements should be between **3** and **4** , and the numbers between them should be **consecutive** , (numbers between them should be ascending or  descending).

Comment: Seems to me you want an algorithm to define if your array has a paired index per value. 
Way to go I think is get all odd numbers and see if they are stepped by 1. If so then your array is an index-value pair.

Comment: So you mean consecutive integers?

Comment: In the code comments what is returned seems to be inconsistent. For array `number1` they seem to want the numbers that aren't consecutive, and yet for `number4` they expect all values. Why are numbers 0,1 and 2 ok as starting integers but 1000 isn't?

Comment: What is the expected output for `[1,1,2,2,3,4]`?

Comment: @Tom ... exactly ... the generic implementation of mine touches exactly this pain point.

Comment: @trincot ... in my opinion any generic approach which ***computes the most reliable longest series of unique values which are either incremented or decremented by the value 1*** should return `[1,1,2,2]` since `3,4` is the only series which fulfills all criteria

Comment: Peter, I don't see how that could be a return value. If elements are removed from the input, those removals should occur at distinct places with **equal** distances between them. I don't see how removing the last two values fits with that.

Comment: It would be nice if the Asker would reply to these remarks.

Comment: @trincot ... you are right. direct antecessors and successors with a difference of 1 should not count as values to be removed. My approach is too strict (I got blind). I have to adapt the constraints about that. And do we both agree that the expected result then was ... `[1,2,4]`?

Comment: @Tom, the Asker should confirm, but for `number4`: it is an all increasing array, which is the first thing to check, and in such a case all that other logic does not apply. `number1` however is not monotone, so then the rest of the logic kicks in.

Comment: Sorry for my delay, I was too busy. For this case `[1,1,2,2,3,4]` should returns this : `[1,2,4]`

Comment: It could also have been `[1,2,3,4]`. Can you explain why it should be `[1,2,4]` and not (with interval of 2) `[1,2,3,4]`? What is the rule that decides it should prefer that?

Comment: Yeah you right ,Both can be true and for handle this special case we can returns empty array or an error.Because the numbers I gave was simple and in my project 99.9% of numbers are float and so difference,So this case is very unlikely to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a separate function that checks whether an input array is monotone (either all descending, or all ascending).

In case the input is not monotone, it requires a bit of tedious checking, but the idea is to find the position of the starting value + 1. If found, then you know the gap size and can verify the rest of this sequence by jumping through the array by that interval, and you can also collect the intermediate values. If the jump exercise confirmed that the "delimiter" values are all incrementing with 1, then you can check that the collected intermediate values are monotone using the function mentioned in the first paragraph.

There is a boundary case where the second value appears multiple times, and more than one possibility exists. This is the case with `[1,0,2,2,3,4]`. It can be broken up into either of these:

- `[1,[0],2,[2],3,[4]]` => `[0,2,4]`, or
- `[1,[0,2],2,[3,4]]` => `[0,2,3,4]`

The solution below will in such case favor the first solution. It is easy to change that behaviour.

Code:

```js
function monotone(numbers) { // Return argument when it is all increasing/decreasing, else []
    if (numbers.length < 2) return numbers;
    let inc = numbers[1] - numbers[0];
    for (let i = 2; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if ((numbers[i] - numbers[i-1]) * inc <= 0) return []; 
    }
    return numbers;
}

function extract(numbers) {
    let test = monotone(numbers);
    // We're done when input is all ascending or descending
    if (test.length == numbers.length) return numbers; 
    let start = numbers[0];
    let gap = numbers.indexOf(start + 1);
    while (gap > 0) {
        if (numbers.length % gap == 0) {
            collect = [];
            for (let j = 0, expect = start; j < numbers.length && numbers[j] === expect; j += gap, expect++) {
                collect.push(...numbers.slice(j + 1, j + gap));
            }
            if (collect.length === numbers.length - (numbers.length / gap)) {
                collect = monotone(collect);
                if (collect.length) return collect;
            }
        }
        gap = numbers.indexOf(start + 1, gap + 1);
    }
    return monotone(numbers);
}

const numbers = {
   number1 : [1, 300,400,2,500,900,3,1000,1100,4,1200,1800], 
   number2 : [0, 1.1, 1, 1.2, 2, 1.3, 3, 1.4],
   number3 : [2, 1000, 3, 980, 4, 700, 5,100, 6, 10],
   number4 : [1000, 1001, 1001.3, 1003, 1014],
   number5 : [34, 76, 0, 50, 0.5, 1010, 0.5],
   trincot:  [1,0,2,2,3,4] 
};

const result = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(numbers).map(([key, numbers]) => [key, extract(numbers)])
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I edited my question and you answer doesn't work for number 1

Comment: I aligned the test case with the update you made, and I can't see a difference. It produces the output you have listed in comments in your code. Can you clarify what you mean with "doesn't work"?

Comment: In my question I mentioned that it doesn't matter how much elements are between the numbers that added +1 every time (1 and 2 or 3 and 4) but your case works for one element between numbers. I edited my question and changed the number1 in numbers object, and you code for this case returned empty array.

Comment: There was a problem with my code. Because the real project is not what I wrote here and it is more complicated and I have combined your code with a part of my own code. Forgive me, I solved it and worked.

Comment: How can I change your code that it works for numbers that are not ascending or descending between their counter? for example for this case `[1,100,2,90,3,101]` returns this : `[100,90,101]`

Comment: Then instead of `collect = monotone(collect); if (collect.length) return collect` just do `return collect`.

Answer (score 0):

The beneath provided generic solution fulfills every of the OP's requirements.

The approach behind the implemented code is based on two helper functions.

The first one computes the longest position list of a series of array indices which have to feature an equal distance to one another while the separating number values are supposed to be either incremented or decremented by the value 1; and since these items separate other array items, they are not allowed to be direct antecessors/successors itself.

The second helper detects strictly monoton number-series in order to return the correct result in case there is no series of numbers where each number value would separate the other array items in a valid way.

```js
function isStrictlyMonoton(arr) {
  const diff = arr[0] - arr[1];

  const isStrict = ((diff < 0)
    && ((a, b) => a < b)) || ((diff > 0)
    && ((a, b) => a > b)) || false;

  return !!isStrict && arr.every((val, idx, arr) => (idx === 0)
    ? isStrict(val, arr[idx + 1])
    : isStrict(arr[idx - 1], val)
  )  
}
function collectValidSeriesOfSeparatorPositions(result, number, idx, arr) {
  // Computes the longest position list of a series of array
  // indices which have to feature an equal distance to one
  // another while the separating number values are supposed
  // to be either incremented or decremented by the value 1.
  // And since these items separate other array items, they
  // are not allowed to be direct antecessors/successors itself.
  const posList = [idx];
  let recentIdx = idx;

  const distance = arr.indexOf((number + 1), (idx + 2)) - idx

  // aggregating.
  while (
    (idx = arr.indexOf((number = number + 1), (idx + distance))) === (recentIdx + distance)
    && idx !== -1
  ) {
    recentIdx = idx;

    posList.push(idx);     
  }
  // validating.
  if (
    (posList.length > 1) &&
    (posList.length > result.length) &&

    ((posList[0] - distance) < 0) &&
    ((posList[posList.length - 1] + distance) > (arr.length - 1))
  ) {
    result = posList;
  }
  return result;
}

function removeSeparatingOneBasedNumberSeriesValues(arr) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) {

    const reversedIndexBase = arr.length - 1;
    const positionList = [

      arr.reduce(collectValidSeriesOfSeparatorPositions, []),

      // shallow copy in order to not mutate the original reference.
      [...arr] 
        .reverse()
        .reduce(collectValidSeriesOfSeparatorPositions, [])
        // re-map/sanitize position values due to the initial `reverse` call.
        .map(idx => reversedIndexBase - idx),

    ].sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)[0];

    if (positionList.length > 1) {

      const positionLookup = Object.fromEntries(
        positionList.map(idx => [idx, true])
      );
      arr = arr.filter((_, idx) => !(idx in positionLookup));

    } else if (!isStrictlyMonoton(arr)) {

      arr = [];
    }
  }
  return arr;
}


Object
  .entries({
    number_1a: [1, 300, 400, 2, 500, 900, 3, 1000, 1100, 4, 1200, 1800],
    number_1b: [1, 300, 2, 400, 3, 500, 4, 600, 5, 800],
    number_2: [0, 1.1, 1.2, 1, 1.3, 1.4, 2],
    number_3: [2, 1000, 3, 980, 4, 700, 5, 100, 6, 10],
    number_4: [1000, 1001, 1001.3, 1003, 1014],
    number_5: [34, 76, 0, 50, 0.5, 1010, 0.5],
    pilchard: [1, 20, 30, 40, 50, 2],
    trincot_A: [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4],
    trincot_B: [1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 4],
    trincot_C: [1, 300, 2, 400, 3, 500, 4, 600, 700, 5, 800]
  })
  .forEach(([key, value]) => {
      console.log(
        `${ key } ... [${ value }] => [${ removeSeparatingOneBasedNumberSeriesValues(value) }]`
      );
      console.log(
        `${ key }/reversed ... [${ [...value].reverse() }] => [${ removeSeparatingOneBasedNumberSeriesValues([...value].reverse()) }]`
      );
  });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @trincot ... I kindly asked for a code review mainly in terms of meeting the requirements as one so far could have gained a common understanding from.

Comment: I think the Asker should do that really, but I would think that when in case `number1` we add a 700 right after the 600, the returned array should be empty, as it is then not conform the rules. So `[1,300,2,400,3,500,4,600,700,5,800]` => `[]`.